# Dynamic SQL Query using loops

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, count

I have 4 tables tab_1, tab_2, tab_3 and tab_4
how can i get the count of all the 4 tables using one single dynamic query?

```
expected result:

count of tab_1 = 
count of tab_2 =
count of tab_3 = 
count of tab_4 =
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your subject talks about using loops which implies a series of queries.  The text of your question asks about writing a single query.  Which of the two is correct?  A single query is going to be quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: Hi justin, many thanks for your response. The query is single whereas the data should be replaced in loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to run four separate queries, not a single query.  It sounds like you're describing something like

```
DECLARE
  TYPE tbl_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
  l_tables tbl_list := tbl_list( 'table_1', 'table_2', 'table_3', 'table_4' );

  l_cnt pls_integer;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_tables.count
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || l_tables(i)
       INTO l_cnt;
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Count of ' ||  l_tables(i) || ' = ' || l_cnt );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: it says tbl_list.count "count" needs to be declared

Comment: @user3663500 - Sorry, I had made a typo.  Fixed.

Comment: Justin i have anthr scernario. can you help me with that please

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  result1 NUMBER; result2 NUMBER; result3 NUMBER; result4 NUMBER;
BEGIN
    select count(*) into result1 from tab_1;
    select count(*) into result2 from tab_2;
    select count(*) into result3 from tab_3;
    select count(*) into result4 from tab_4;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('count of tab_1=' || result1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('count of tab_2=' || result2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('count of tab_3=' || result3);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('count of tab_4=' || result4);

END;
```

Comment: Hi TechDo, this one works. But the problem is i dont want to write 4 slect queries and 4 dbms_output. The select query needs to be sattic and the table names should be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Although I fail to see why you would want this, you ask, we answer.

To squish this all into 1 single query, you could try using 3 scalar subqueries in 1 main query from dual.

Select (Select Count(*) From tab_1) As CountOfTab1,
       (Select Count(*) From tab_2) As CountOfTab2,
       (Select Count(*) From tab_3) As CountOfTab3,
       (Select Count(*) From tab_4) As CountOfTab4
Into   countOfTab1,
       countOfTab2,
       countOfTab3,
       countOfTab4
From   Dual